# Pushing rails app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I followed the setup for Heroku, and created a repository called escene, which I then cloned to my desktop. However, I already have an app developed and linked to github, Appversionzero, which I want to upload to Heroku.

I navigated to my Appversionzero directory, checked my remotes added my heroku profile with 'heroku git:remote -a escene' so I have:

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/escene.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/escene.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/Keenangp/appversionzero.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Keenangp/appversionzero.git (push)
```

but I receive this error:

```
`To https://git.heroku.com/escene.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/escene.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`
```

Is this because the cloned repository in my local files is still linked to the app on heroku? In sum, I need to set up a remote linking my Appversionzero to my heroku ref. so I can push it with 'git push heroku master'.

Thanks
(edit: I see that the escene clone actually ended up in my Appversionzero's root directory.)

Comment: firstly you need to pull the project and then push it back ...tell me if it doesn't works

Comment: I tried 'git pull https://git.heroku.com/escene.git' received a list of all of the conflicts (I'm assuming files and folders that are replicated), and attempted to push again, but received the same error (until errors are fixed). Maybe I should delete the cloned directories?

Comment: try this git commit -am 'Conflict resolved' and then pull a project

Comment: hello did it work?

Comment: Hi, apologies, no unfortunately I merged the two together and riddled it with conflicts. I was able to salvage some of the code, but I will have to start the project over. This time without making the same mistake. :) Thanks